# How does zookeeper determine the 'java.library.path' for a hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, oozie

I am running hadoop jobs on a distributed cluster using oozie. I give a setting 'oozie.libpath' for the oozie jobs.

Recently, I have deleted few of my older version jar files from the library path oozie uses and I have replaced them with newer versions. However, when I run my hadoop job, my older version of jar files and newer version of jar files both get loaded and the mapreduce is still using the older version.

I am not sure where zookeeper is loading the jar files from. Are there any default settings that it loads the jar files from ? There is only one library path in my HDFS and it does not have those jar files.

Answer (score -1):

I have found what is going wrong. The wrong jar is shipped with my job file. Should have check here first